# reload the same component when we access it from two different menu item

Tags: angular

I have a menu that display the same component, but with different data on every menu item. The issue is that when I display the component by one item menu and enter certain data (not all data that I change, but certain secondary data), when I access the component from a different menu item it remembers the data from the first select. I would like to reload completely the component so that it discard the data from the first select

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it is enough to listen to a route change

```
router.events.subscribe((_val) => {
  // re initialization
})
```